# Monad for a Rose tree

Tags: haskell

I have this data type

```
> data Rose a
>   = RoseNode a [Rose a]
>   | RoseLeaf
```

And I need to make a monad instance for it.
Here's my atempt

```
> instance Monad Rose where
>    return = RoseNode
>    RoseNode a rs >>= f = RoseNode (f a) (rs >>= f)
>    RoseLeaf >>= _ = RoseLeaf
```

But I'm getting this error

```
app\Main.lhs:599:15: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Rose a] -> Rose a' with `Rose a'
      Expected type: a -> Rose a
        Actual type: a -> [Rose a] -> Rose a
    * Probable cause: `RoseNode' is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: RoseNode
      In an equation for `return': return = RoseNode
      In the instance declaration for `Monad Rose'
    * Relevant bindings include
        return :: a -> Rose a (bound at app\Main.lhs:599:6)
    |
599 | >    return = RoseNode
    |               ^^^^^^
```

and this one

```
app\Main.lhs:601:51: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Rose' with `[]'
      Expected type: Rose a -> [b]
        Actual type: a -> Rose b
    * In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `f'
      In the second argument of `RoseNode', namely `(rs >>= f)'
      In the expression: RoseNode (f a) (rs >>= f)
    |
601 | >    RoseNode a rs >>= f = RoseNode (f a) (rs >>= f)
    |
```

How do I fix those?

**Edit**
Here's the Applicative for Rose

```
> instance Applicative Rose where
>     pure x = RoseNode x []
>     (<*>) _ RoseLeaf = RoseLeaf
>     (<*>) RoseLeaf _ = RoseLeaf
>     (<*>) (RoseNode f rosa) n@(RoseNode x subrosa) = RoseNode (f x) (map (fmap f) subrosa ++ map (<*> n) rosa)
```

Comment: Look at the type of `return`. Look at the type of `RoseNode`. What can you do to make those types match?

Comment: Can you describe what part of the error messages aren't clear to you? They *are* telling you the problems. Learning to read them is important.

Comment: Aside from the specific problems here, note that you can't write a `Monad` instance without also having `Functor` and `Applicative` instances for the same type. Now there are "automatic" ways you can make these when you already have a Monad instance, that you could just copy-paste into your code - but since those typeclasses are a step down in complexity it might help if you first try to implement them (first `Functor`, then `Applicative`) before tackling the more complex `Monad` instance.

Comment: @Carl I understand the problems like on the second error, but I don't know how to solve it because I haven't seen an example of a monad on a list so I don't know how to solve that one

Comment: @RobinZigmond I already made them

Comment: @CarlosMelo OK thanks - but I find that surprising because `return` for a Monad is (or should be) exactly the same as `pure` for Applicative, so a working Applicative instance for this type would already tell you how to write `return`. And your `return` here doesn't even have the correct type.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Using what I made in pure worked. Now the only error left is the second one. Do you know how to use the >>= on the list?

Comment: One technique that can be helpful is to use *typed holes*. If you're not sure what to put somewhere, write `_` instead (or `_1`, `_whatever`, or anything else starting with an underscore). GHC will tell you the type it expects there, and also the types of various things around there. This can make your job *much* easier.

Comment: If you rewrote `pure` in point-free style, you'd get `pure = flip RoseNode []`, not `pure = RoseNode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was this a homework exercise?  If so, was the `Rose` data type given to you, or did you come up with it yourself?  It's possible that you were *supposed* to come up with a different `Rose` type, with the values in the leaves instead of the nodes, because the monad instance for leaf-value rose trees is much more obvious than the monad for node-value rose trees.

As you know, for a list, the monadic bind operation `lst >>= f` uses `f` to replace each value in the original list with a sublist, and then it "flattens" the result, so it's still a list of values, instead of a list of lists of values.

Similarly, for a tree, the monadic bind operation `tree >>= f` should apply `f` to replace each value in the tree with a subtree, and then "flatten" the result, so it's still a tree of values, instead of a tree of trees of values.

Specifically, for a rose tree with the values in the leaves, the intended definition of `rose >>= f` is straightforward -- it should replace each leaf-value with a leaf-tree, and then "flatten" the result, so the new subtrees are grafted on to the original tree.

For a rose tree with the values in the nodes, it's tougher to figure out what's supposed to happen.  Each value in a node should be replaced by a subtree, but it's a little hard to figure out how to "flatten" the result, since it's not as simple as grafting subtrees onto the leaves.  At each node, you've got the new subtree, and then you've also got the main tree branches under that node, each a tree of subtrees that need to be flattened.  I guess the obvious possibilities are to (1) concatenate the node's subtree with the flattening of the other branches under that node; or (2) concatenate them in the opposite order, first flattening of other branches under that node, then the node's subtree.

It looks like your applicative instance implements the equivalent of (1).

So, the instances you probably want are:

```
data Rose a
  = RoseNode a [Rose a]
  | RoseLeaf
  deriving (Functor)
instance Applicative Rose where
  pure x = RoseNode x []
  (<*>) _ RoseLeaf = RoseLeaf
  (<*>) RoseLeaf _ = RoseLeaf
  (<*>) (RoseNode f rosa) n@(RoseNode x subrosa) 
    = RoseNode (f x) (map (fmap f) subrosa ++ map (<*> n) rosa)
instance Monad Rose where
  RoseLeaf >>= _ = RoseLeaf
  RoseNode x branches >>= f = case f x of
    RoseLeaf -> RoseLeaf
    RoseNode y branches' -> RoseNode y (branches' ++ fmap (>>= f) branches)
```

Note that you need not define `return` because it defaults to `pure`.

You can ensure that the applicative and monad instances are "compatible" by comparing `(<*>)` from the `Applicative` instance with `ap` from `Control.Monad`, which implements `(<*>)` using monadic operations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad

data Rose a
  = RoseNode a [Rose a]
  | RoseLeaf
  deriving (Functor, Show)
instance Applicative Rose where
  pure x = RoseNode x []
  (<*>) _ RoseLeaf = RoseLeaf
  (<*>) RoseLeaf _ = RoseLeaf
  (<*>) (RoseNode f rosa) n@(RoseNode x subrosa)
    = RoseNode (f x) (map (fmap f) subrosa ++ map (<*> n) rosa)
instance Monad Rose where
  RoseLeaf >>= _ = RoseLeaf
  RoseNode x branches >>= f = case f x of
    RoseLeaf -> RoseLeaf
    RoseNode y branches' -> RoseNode y (branches' ++ fmap (>>= f) branches)

t1 = RoseNode (+1) [RoseNode (+2) [], RoseNode (+3) []]
t2 = RoseNode 17 [RoseNode 23 [], RoseNode 29 []]

main = do
  print $ t1 <*> t2
  print $ t1 `ap` t2
```